# MS Access Error 3265 'item not found in this collection' when opening form in add mode

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form with a listbox with multiple selections allowed. The form is set up so that the selections are saved in a separate table. It works fine when the form is opened in edit mode.

However, when I set up the form to open in add mode instead, I get this error when i click on an item in the listbox. How do I get the code to work when the form is opened in add mode? I am not a developer so don't know where to start. Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub Lst_Events_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Err_lst_events_AfterUpdate

   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim blnInTransaction As Boolean
   Dim varItem As Variant

   ' Make sure the current vendor record has been saved.
   If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False

   Set ws = Workspaces(0)
   Set db = ws.Databases(0)

   ws.BeginTrans
   blnInTransaction = True

   ' Delete all events now on record.
   strSQL = "DELETE FROM tbl_EventsSupported " & _
            "WHERE Vendorid = " & Me.ID

   db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

   ' Add each event selected in the list box.
   With Me.lst_events
      For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
        strSQL = _
            "INSERT INTO tbl_EventsSupported " & _
                "(vendorID, EventID) VALUES (" & _
                Me.ID & ", " & .ItemData(varItem) & ")"
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
      Next varItem
    End With

   ws.CommitTrans
   blnInTransaction = False

Exit_lst_events_AfterUpdate:
   Set db = Nothing
   Set ws = Nothing
   Exit Sub

Err_lst_events_AfterUpdate:
   MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
       vbExclamation, "Unable to Update"
   If blnInTransaction Then
       ws.Rollback
       blnInTransaction = False
   End If
   Resume Exit_lst_events_AfterUpdate
End Sub
```

Comment: What line errs out? Is `Me.ID` entered on form in add mode?

Comment: How is value for ID generated? If on NewRecord row, need to enter data to a bound field in order to trigger generation of autonumber ID. Then commit that record to table before saving related records from the listbox selections.

Comment: AfterUpdate event of listbox is not appropriate for multi-select listbox. It will run after each item is clicked on so it will run the loop each time and attempt to create records for all selected items. Usual approach is to have button user would click when they complete selecting items.